# How do I obtain the latest tweet from someone with tweepy?

Tags: python, twitter, tweepy

I'm trying to get the latest tweet from an account and then automatically tweeting that with my bot account and I used this, but it doesn't seem to work:

```
def user_tweet(twitter):
    statuses = api.GetUserTimeline(screen_name=twitter)
    return statuses[0].text

if __name__ == "__main__":
    latest_tweet = user_tweet(sys.argv[1])
    api.update_status(latest_tweet)
time.sleep(3)
```

Is there a "quicker" way to do this? And how do I solve this?

Comment: What exactly is your problem? Is it not working or do you want it quicker? Please clarify a bit.

Comment: both really, I never used tweepy before so I'm a newbie, I just looked at a few people's code and tried making my own, other than the access tokens, this is the only code in my program. It's not working, it says "IndexError: list index out of range" on the line "latest_tweet = user_tweet(sys.argv[1])"

Comment: you need to run your file like this `python filename.py twitter_id`. Then this error will be resolved. Also please add all erros into your question. That will help others to debug.

Answer (score 1):

```
def user_tweet(twitter):
    statuses = api.user_timeline(screen_name=twitter)
    return statuses[0].text

if __name__ == "__main__":
    latest_tweet = user_tweet(sys.argv[1])
    api.update_status(latest_tweet)
time.sleep(3)
```

This was the solution! :)